# ¿Porque la barra del menu de navegacion se muestra delgada?

Tags: html

Estoy diseñando una web para compra de videojuegos y obtengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como veran trabajo con Bootstrap 5 y html5
el codigo es el siguiente:

stylos.css:

```
.header {
    color: #a3b1bf;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif, arial, Verdana;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100000;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0
}



.navbar-fullscreen {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    /* Inicialmente, la barra de navegación tiene un ancho de 0 */
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #343a40;
    /* Color de fondo oscuro */
    padding-top: 3.5rem;
    /* Ajusta el espacio superior para evitar solapamiento con la barra de navegación */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Oculta el desbordamiento horizontal */
    transition: width 0.3s;
    /* Agrega una transición suave al ancho */
}

.navbar-fullscreen.active {
    width: 100%;
    /* Cuando está activa, la barra de navegación se ensancha al 100% */
}

.navbar-fullscreen a {
    color: #fff;
    /* Color del texto en el menú */
}

.navbar {

    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10;
    z-index: 1000000;
    height: 1000%;
    /* O cualquier valor mayor que el z-index del header */
}

#carouselExample {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
    /* O ajusta según sea necesario */
}

.navegacion {
    color: #a3b1bf;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif, arial, Verdana;

    float: left;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 550px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    flex-direction: row;
    /* Alinear elementos en columna en dispositivos móviles */

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

mi archivo index.html

```
<body>
    <header class="header">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="top-areas d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="navegacion">
                    <h1 class="logo-area" style="margin-right: auto;">
                        <a href="index.html"><img class="lazy" src="logo.272x92-2.png" alt="Logo de mi página"
                                width="262.5" height="39.5"></a>
                    </h1>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select class="form-select">

                            <option value="1">Juego</option>
                            <option value="2">Producto</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Madden NFL 24" aria-label="Buscar"
                            aria-describedby="basic-addon2" />
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-label="Search Games"></i>
                    </div>

              
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="CurrencyDropdownMenu"
                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span> USD
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="CurrencyDropdownMenu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span>
                                    USD</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-eu"></span>
                                    EUR</a></li>

                            <!-- Agrega más idiomas según sea necesario -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-signup-dropdown">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="loginSignupDropdown"
                                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-user"></i> My Account
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="loginSignupDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registrarse</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-button">
                        <button class="cart-button" type="button"
                            style="background-color: transparent; border: none; height: auto;">
                            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-fullscreen" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Menú
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-bottom" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Opción 1</a>
                            <
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    

    <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="banner22.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="Imagen 1">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="banner22.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="Imagen 2">
            </div>
            <!-- Agrega más imágenes según sea necesario -->
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev"
            style="height: 50%;margin-top: 200px;">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Anterior</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Siguiente</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <script>
        function toggleNavbar() {
          document.querySelector('.navbar-fullscreen').classList.toggle('active');
        }
      </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/js/all.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Me gustaría poner una barra de navegación con un botón hamburguesa que despliegue un menú a todo el ancho de la web.

No se que mas puedo hacer para mejorar la maquetación pero hago lo mejor posible. en el body tengo la barra principal con lagunas opción de idioma y moneda y el estado actual del carrito de compra mas el login/sign in, debajo iría el menú con las categorías de juegos disponibles entre otras opciones.